# how to get slack notification on change of Kubernetes pod status?

Tags: kubernetes, notifications, slack

How to get slack notification while any k8s pod status changed? can't use kube bots as it's not allowed in my organisation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "Alertmanager" from the Prometheus stack for such notifications.
Once you have the prometheus stack up and running, you can configure custom alerts based on any property of objects in kubernetes and forward them to slack

https://github.com/coreos/prometheus-operator/blob/master/Documentation/user-guides/alerting.md

**Updated:**

In case you can't deploy any external tool, you could right a simple shell script which gets pod status via `kubectl`

Something like:

```
kubectl get pods mypod -ojson | jq .status.phase
```

You can poll on this command and use the slack [webhooks](https://api.slack.com/messaging/webhooks) to send a notification when it changes value

Comment: Thanks for quick reply Hazim, prometheus is very good option but not allowed to install any package on prod server. is it possible only through scripting or like that ?

Comment: Yes that should be possible, I have updated the answer @NiladriDey

Answer (score 0):

I implemented solution using kubernetes api
https://github.com/kubernetes-client/csharp/tree/master/examples/watch

Basically it will check the not running pod and notify using Microsoft Teams web-hook. It will also notify pod which was initially not running and came back to running status again(recovered pod)

C# code snippet below with Main and Notify function.

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Load from the default kubeconfig on the machine.
            var config = KubernetesClientConfiguration.BuildConfigFromConfigFile();

            // Use the config object to create a client.
            var client = new Kubernetes(config);


            try
            {

                var podlistResp = await client.ListNamespacedPodWithHttpMessagesAsync(Namespace, watch: true);
                using (podlistResp.Watch<V1Pod, V1PodList>(async (type, item) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(type);
                    Console.WriteLine("==on watch event==");
                    var message = $"Namespace: {Namespace} Pod: {item.Metadata.Name} Type: {type}  Phase:{item.Status.Phase}";
                    var remessage = $"Namespace: {Namespace} Pod: {item.Metadata.Name} Type: {type} back to Phase:{item.Status.Phase}";
                    Console.WriteLine(message);
                    if (!item.Status.Phase.Equals("Running") && !item.Status.Phase.Equals("Succeeded"))
                    {   Console.WriteLine("==on watch event==");
                        await Notify(message);
                        Console.WriteLine("==on watch event==");
                    }
                    if ( type== WatchEventType.Modified && item.Status.Phase.Equals("Running") )
                    {   Console.WriteLine("==on watch event==");
                        await Notify(remessage);
                        Console.WriteLine("==on watch event==");
                    }
                }))
                {
                    
                    Console.WriteLine("press ctrl + c to stop watching");

                    var ctrlc = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);
                    Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, eventArgs) => ctrlc.Set();
                    ctrlc.Wait();
                }
            }
            
            catch (System.Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Error.WriteLine($"An error happened Message: {ex.Message}", ex);
            }
        }

        private static async Task Notify(string message)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://outlook.office.com");
                var body = new { text = message };
                var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body));
                var result = await client.PostAsync("https://outlook.office.com/webhook/xxxx/IncomingWebhook/xxx", content);
                result.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use kwatch, which sends Slack notifications on crashes -
https://github.com/abahmed/kwatch